# Align two equations vertically

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to vertically align two equations but I fail to get it right.

```
$\begin{aligned} 
   f_{s_{i}}=-\frac{w_{s}}{n_{i}}\sum_{j=1}^{n}g(d_{ij})d_{ij} \\
    g(d_{ij}) =
  \begin{cases} 
    1 & d_{ij}\leq r_{h}\\
    exp(-\frac{(d_{ij}-r_{h})^{2}}{\sigma^{2}})   & d_{ij}> r_{h}
  \end{cases}
\end{aligned}$
```

I get the following:
[image]

How can I align the equation 'f' and 'g' knowing that they are presented in a table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use on these, depending on  whether you want  to align the `=` signs or the beginning of each line. Remember that `aligned` (or `align`) requires marking the alignment point with an ampersand:

```
$\begin{aligned} 
   f_{s_{i}} &=-\frac{w_{s}}{n_{i}}\sum_{j=1}^{n}g(d_{ij})d_{ij} \\
    g(d_{ij}) &=
  \begin{cases} 
    1 & d_{ij}\leq r_{h}\\
    \exp\Bigl(-\frac{(d_{ij}-r_{h})^{2}}{\sigma^{2}}\Bigr)   & d_{ij}> r_{h}
  \end{cases}
\end{aligned}$ 

$\begin{aligned} 
   &f_{s_{i}} =-\frac{w_{s}}{n_{i}}\sum_{j=1}^{n}g(d_{ij})d_{ij} \\
   &g(d_{ij})  =
  \begin{cases} 
    1 & d_{ij}\leq r_{h}\\
    \exp\bigl(-\frac{(d_{ij}-r_{h})^{2}}{\sigma^{2}}\bigr)   & d_{ij}> r_{h}
  \end{cases}
\end{aligned}$
```

I added two different sizes for the parentheses after `exp` in the two proposed codes.

Unrelated: like all usual functions having a name, the `exp` function should typed in upshape, which is obtained with the command `\exp`   (like `\sin, \cos, \log, &c.`)

[image]

Comment: +1. I would increase the size of the round parentheses around the fraction term in the second row of the `cases` environment, though.

Comment: @Mico: You're right. I didn't have time when I , posted to  check this point, but I've added size commands (different in each proposed code, as none is perfect in this respect). Thanks for reminding me!

Comment: It's more usual to set such expressions in display form, not as in-line math.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I don't think that, for the fraction in the cases environment, the display form looks so nice. Personally, I would rather use  `\mfrac`, but I didn't want to complexify my answer.

Comment: Okay, legitimate personal preference.  But then you're giving up the horizontal centering, "separation" above and below, and possibility of numbering, that come with a display environment.  (I really hate to encourage the use of `\\ ` to break lines, and just setting something like this as a separate paragraph would probably result in followup questions.)

Comment: I didn't give up whatever myself, I only respected what  the O.P. had posted – I thought maybe  he/she had good reasons for using the inline mode.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use the & charactere whereever you want to put the alignment.

For example, if you want to align at the left side of the column:

```
$\begin{aligned} 
   & f_{s_{i}}=-\frac{w_{s}}{n_{i}}\sum_{j=1}^{n}g(d_{ij})d_{ij} \\
   & g(d_{ij}) =
  \begin{cases} 
    1 & d_{ij}\leq r_{h}\\
    exp(-\frac{(d_{ij}-r_{h})^{2}}{\sigma^{2}})   & d_{ij}> r_{h}
  \end{cases}
\end{aligned}$
```

else, if you want to align in the = charactere, you do as:

```
$\begin{aligned} 
   f_{s_{i}} & =-\frac{w_{s}}{n_{i}}\sum_{j=1}^{n}g(d_{ij})d_{ij} \\
   g(d_{ij}) & =
  \begin{cases} 
    1 & d_{ij}\leq r_{h}\\
    exp(-\frac{(d_{ij}-r_{h})^{2}}{\sigma^{2}})   & d_{ij}> r_{h}
  \end{cases}
\end{aligned}$
```

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) What difference is there between Bernard's answer and yours?

Comment: I actually didn't read his code (just now that you said), I just did with examples and explained the cases. Whereas he hasn't. Anyway, the two will give the same result.